# `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- active_support/concern (MissingSourceFile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

I'm working on a Rails 2.3.8 project.  I've cloned the project to my server but can't get the app to start.  Below is the error I get.  I've heard that you can install Bundler for 2.3.8 which may solve the problem but was wondering if I'm just missing something.  The concern gem *is* installed as a local gem.

Thanks so much for your help.

```
** Daemonized, any open files are closed.  Look at log/mongrel.pid and log/mongrel.log for info.
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:12005
** Starting Rails with development environment...
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- active_support/concern (MissingSourceFile)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `polyglot_original_require'
    from /home/ankasa/ruby/gems/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/ankasa/ruby/gems/gems/paperclip-3.0.0/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `polyglot_original_require'
    from /home/ankasa/ruby/gems/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/ankasa/ruby/gems/gems/paperclip-3.0.0/lib/paperclip.rb:47
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `polyglot_original_require'
    from /home/ankasa/ruby/gems/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/ankasa/ruby/gems/gems/paperclip-3.0.0/lib/paperclip/railtie.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `polyglot_original_require'
    from /home/ankasa/ruby/gems/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/ankasa/ruby/gems/gems/paperclip-3.0.0/rails/init.rb:1:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
    from /home/ankasa/rails_apps/ankasa/config/../lib/spree/initializer.rb:113:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/ankasa/rails_apps/ankasa/config/../lib/spree/initializer.rb:90:in `run'
    from /home/ankasa/rails_apps/ankasa/config/environment.rb:13
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in `rails'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in `cloaker_'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:99:in `cloaker_'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using too new a paperclip -- you need to make sure its v2.7, not the 3.0 in your stack trace:

from /home/ankasa/ruby/gems/gems/paperclip-3.0.0/rails/init.rb:1:in `evaluate_init_rb'

there's more in the paperclip README but basically Rails 2.3 support was dropped in Paperclip 3.0

Comment: Yay, it's working! I installed paperclip 2.7, then got an error: can't activate activesupport (= 3.2.2, runtime) for [], already activated activesupport-2.3.8 for ["rails-2.3.8"  .  So I uninstall activesupport 3.2.2, which I guess was installed with paperclip 2.7.  Then I got the error: !!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.  So I installed the mysql gem. AND VOILA!

Comment: Bundler really helps out with that kind of stuff. Or RVM with a project-specific gem set.